# what's wrong with my file upload code?

Tags: php

I don't know what the problem is. After file upload from a post form i check it with:

```
if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'])){
$pic_error="<p>file upload error</p>";
}
else{
do something
};
```

it does not `do something` which means file is not uploaded. When I echo `$_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']` it prints the file `tmp_name`, it even prints the file's size.

I'm using `multipart/form-data` on my form.

What is the problem here? Is there a problem from host?(like deactivating file upload or something?)

the problem still remains, i activated display errors and it says:

```
Warning: is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string
```

but when i echo $_FILES['pic']['error']['0']; it echo 0 witch means there are no error in uploading files!
if it's relative i should say i have several file inputs:

```
            if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic-1']['tmp_name'])){
                $pic_1_error="<p>error</p>";
            };
            if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic-2']['tmp_name'])){
                $pic_2_error="<p>error</p>";
            };
            if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic-3']['tmp_name'])){
                $pic_3_error="<p>error</p>";
            };
```

edit:
by using var_dump($_FILES);
i got this:

```
 ["pic-1"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "33333333333.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/php3ggYlE" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(81200) } } ["pic-2"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "728.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpucuBbg" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(32639) } } ["pic-3"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "33333333333.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpz6vehT" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(81200) } }
```

which does mean all files have been uploaded correctly(dose not?).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: ^ check the error, but I can almost guarantee it is that the directory you are uploading to isn't giving permission to be written to

Comment: @samrap in that case, it should run the `do something code` because i first check if file is uploaded, then check if file type is valid and then use move_uploaded_file.

Comment: have you checked the error yet?

Comment: the error is 0, i think the problem is from is_uploaded_file, how else can i check if file is uploaded?

Comment: Start with `var_dump($_FILES)`, *see* what you're trying to work with!

Comment: why $_FILES['pic']['error'] **['0']**? Have you turned notices and warnings on in error_reporting? And yes, a `var_dump($_FILES);` would be very welcome.

Comment: @syck yes i have turned theme on. var_dump show that the file upload is correct(i add it into the question).

Comment: @the110boy You answer is down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I used JQuery for image preview before upload. It was changing file inputs, but I didn't know it. For example:
from

```
<input type="file" name="pic1" />
```

to

```
<input type="file" name="pic1-[]" />
```

That was the source of all my problems in PHP.

Comment: Well, I hope I helped narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge sure u did.

Answer (score 1):

The 'if-else' conditional you have written should **not end** in a semi-colon (;).

This is best achieved with a `for` loop.
Just winging it, without security stuff added ...

```
define('FILE_UPLOAD_LIMIT', 5);
$numFiles        = null;
$errors          = [];

/*I do not have time to do a complete validation here. I would use loops, anyway.*/
try
{
    if(is_array($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES) &&
        isset($_FILES['files']) && is_array($_FILES['files']) && !empty($_FILES['files']) &&
        isset($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']) && is_array($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']) && !empty($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']) &&
        isset($_FILES['files']['error']) && is_array($_FILES['files']['error']) && !empty($_FILES['files']['error']))
    {
        $numFiles = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);

        if($numFiles > FILE_UPLOAD_LIMIT)
        {
            $_FILES = [];
            throw new DomainException("Too many files uploaded");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new DomainException("No files were uploaded.");
    }
}
catch(DomainException de)
{
     //Handle it.
}

for($i = 0; $i < $numFiles; $i++)
{
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i]) && ($_FILES['files']['error'][$i] === 0))
    {
        //Do something security related.
        //Do something with the file.
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[$i] = "<p>File upload error on file #" . ($i + 1) . "</p>";
    }//<------No semi-colon here.
}
```

Also, check your php.ini for $_POST, file, processing limit related settings. Check all necessary file permissions in the temp folder and the folder you want to move files to. Above all, if you are uploading multiple files at the same time add the `[]` next to the name attribute's value in your HTML5. Make sure to use the `multiple="multiple"` attribute as well.

```
<form id="fileUploadForm" name="fileUploadForm_" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="foo.php">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">
    <!--blah-->
</form>
```

[http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php](http://PHP%20Manual:%20Uploading%20multiple%20files.)

Comment: Certainly, it's better than what is in the question.

Comment: sorry i didn't get that, you mean the last ";" after "}"? i think this will make the code more optimized. show where the code ends. is that wrong?

Comment: @the110boy I would have to research it to give a definitive answer, but as far as I know, this is not valid syntax in PHP. Statements end in a semi-colon, but block statements should not end in a semi-colon. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php

Comment: Good basic answer. Answers the question well.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your `var_dump` output, each array contains a further array. It's actually:

```
$_FILES['pic-1']['tmp_name'][0]
```

Are you by any chance declaring the input in your form with `name="pic-1[]"`? That would explain the superfluous inner array.